# How do I save my refresh token in my application when user doesn't log in frequently?

Tags: c#, refresh-token

Updated question:

I have an application that needs to import data from an external API. This API hands out an authorization code that is valid for 10 minutes. With this auth code I can make a GET request to receive an access token and refresh token. The access token is valid for an hour.

The access tokens that are handed out needs to be shared between users of the same company.

How do I store these tokens in a secure way?

Let's say the users doesn't log in for a few days, then I don't want to have to go through the whole process with the auth code again.

So my two questions are:

1. Where do I save the tokens?
2. How should I go about refreshing the refresh token? An example could be that the users doesnt log in for 2 months, and then the refresh token has expired. Do I update it with scheduled jobs?

Comment: Did you look for documentations? There are really good articles: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens-in-net-6-0/

Comment: put the refresh token in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I updated the question, I forgot to mention that the API is external and that the tokens are company-unique, so users of the same company are sharing the same tokens.

Comment: @BagusTesa Thanks! I updated my question. Forgot to mention that it's an external API that gives company-unique tokens, so all users for company A shares the same access_token

Comment: *"The tokens are shared between users of the same company."* - is your application.. the one that consume this token thing then provide service(s) to the users in your company? initially i thought your app issuing tokens.

Comment: No so my application works by itself, the user login works fine. But in the application they need to import data from another application and they do this by using their api. So the tokens that this api is giving out needs to be stored somewhere and shared between the users of the same company. @BagusTesa

Comment: the simplest thing is just to put the token into a file (or database) somewhere close by to your app. if your app is long-lived, you have the option to keep them in memory. alternatively, use the [key storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) provided by .net core.

Comment: @BagusTesa Thank you!! Wasn't sure if it was considered ok or not to save to DB.

Comment: though, keep in mind regarding your threat model though. do consult with security team (if exist). some hates saving tokens in memory not in a `SecuredString` form - despite the fact, you have to unmarshall the secure stuff into normal `String` to be utilized (which causes string residue in memory for some time until garbage collection destroys it). security is fickle at times ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯